# R8 -printusage not worked

Tags: android, minify, android-r8

I use R8 in my project to minify classes and it worked well, now I want to see what classes was removed exactly and from [Android offical](https://stackoverflow.com) it said add : `-printusage proguard/unused.txt` in my proguard file and I did so, but after run task assembleRelease there is neither `usage.txt` below mapping folder nor `unused.txt` below `proguard` which I configed before.

this is what generated below `build/intermediates/outputs/mapping/release`:

```
- configuration.txt
- mapping.txt
- resources.txt
- seeds.txt
```

Is there somebody can help me generating usage.txt from R8, THX...

Answer (score 0):

The removed items is written by default to `app/build/outputs/mapping/release/usage.txt` without any need to add `-printusage` to the configuration file.

If you want to use `-printusage` then be careful with relative paths. In you case (the additional copy of) the file ends up in `app/proguard/usage.txt`.

Comment: thanks, but I remove -printusage config there's still no usage.txt after build release with minifyEnabled=true...

Comment: Interesting - which version of AGP are you using?

Comment: with AGP8.2.2 + Gradle8.0, but in lower version which AGP7.2.2 + Gradle7.5.1 it's the same...

Comment: Just tested with a small sample project. With `-printusage proguard/usage.txt` in `app/proguard-rules.pro` and `isMinifyEnabled = true` running `./gradlew :app:assembleRelease` I get the following `usage.txt` files: `app/build/outputs/mapping/release/usage.txt` and `app/proguard/usage.txt`. Can you create a small sample project demonstration the issue that you can share?